# Are there alternatives to OptionMenu that can store other data than just strings?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm  currently working on a project and i need the user to choose an option which will trigger something. The problem is that I have to check all the cases and i have quite a lot of options.

Here is what the code would look like:

```py
def check(variable):
    if (variable.get() == "GroupA"):
        GroupA.doSomething()
    elif (variable.get() == "GroupB"):
        GroupB.doSomething()
    ...
    elif (variable.get() == "GroupZ"):
        GroupZ.doSomething()
```

Is there a more elegant way to code this other than just to hard code it? Or is there another drop down tool i can use in tkinter(It would be perfect if i could store another object which could be accessed along with the string)?

Comment: You should be able to use a Python dictionary to map the possible values of `variable` to any other object (including functions and methods) you want — which would only require one or maybe two lines of code to access after it's set up. You can also do things like looking up variable names (strings) in the global namespace (which is like a dictionary) to access the value currently associated with them. In other words, I don't think you need an alternative.

Comment: I didn't think about dictionaries, thanks for the nice solution!

Comment: @TheS1: **"Is there a more elegant way"**: Provide a [mcve], i'm sure there is.